# Where are my offline JSBin Files Located?

Tags: jsbin

For example, how would I get to http://localhost:3000/ten/1/ (http://localhost:3000/ten/1/) ?

Answer (score 0):

So do you run JSBin locally? Because in that case the bins aren't saved as files, but in a mySQL database using SQLite. But you can look up your html/css/js code by the url http://localhost:3000/ten.html. If you have written code in processors like Sass or coffescript you can look them up as well e.g.  http://localhost:3000/ten.sass. 
 Unfortunately I don't know how to access the the database.